# Solving system of ODEs linearised around steady state

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, linearization

I have been given some lecture notes that explain how to solve a system of ODEs linearised around steady state. All the steps are clear except the following statements:

- $J(x^\ast)$ is real and symmetric <-- How can I show this?
- We can write all vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$ as linear combinations of the eigenvectors of $J(x^\ast)$ <-- What is a good reference to understand this step?
- $x(t) = x^\ast + \sum_{n=1}^\infty \exp(\lambda_n t) c_n e_n$ <-- How can $\exp(\lambda_n t)$ be brought inside the summation? If it's a typo, how should it be corrected?

Can someone help clarify them please?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: "symmetric" is in general wrong. You get symmetric Jacobians from gradient systems, $\dot x=\nabla \phi(x)$, but in general you can get any matrix, just consider the corresponding linear system.

Comment: What do you mean by "corresponding"? Do you mean the system presented here which leads to a non-symmetric Jacobian?

Comment: Take any matrix $M$. Use $A(x)=Mx$. Then $J(x)=M$.